# Python Dictionary write data into xls file

Tags: python, dictionary, xls

I am trying to write my dictionary into an xls file.

My dictionary has following structure:

```
[{'Route Nr.': 1,
'City Nr.': 0,
'City Name': 'EMTE HEADQUARTERS VEGHEL', 
'Total Distance in Route (km)': 0, 
'Total Distance (km)': 0}, 
{'Route Nr.': 1, 
'City Nr.': 78, 
'City Name': 'EMTE OLDEBROEK FR', 
'Total Distance in Route (km)': 97, 
'Total Distance (km)': 97}]'
```

The keys should become the column names and the values the rows.
Like this:

[image: Excel output]

I have tried using pandas but I didn't manage to get it working properly

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow :) Would you mind sharing with us what you have already tried? This would surely allow for better answers, based on your concrete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a lot of ways to do it, here is my version of the answer:

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = <YOUR LIST OF DICTIONARIES>

df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
df.to_excel(r'exaple.xls', index = False)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
data = [{'Route Nr.': 1, 'City Nr.': 0, 'City Name': 'EMTE HEADQUARTERS VEGHEL', 'Total Distance in Route (km)': 0, 'Total Distance (km)': 0}, {'Route Nr.': 1, 'City Nr.': 78, 'City Name': 'EMTE OLDEBROEK FR', 'Total Distance in Route (km)': 97, 'Total Distance (km)': 97}]

header = ','.join(data[0].keys()) + '\n'

f = open('output.xls','w')
f.write(header)
for line in range(len(data)):
    f.write(','.join(str(element) for element in data[line].values())+'\n')

f.close()
```

Output: 
[image: output.xls]